# How can I access various UIViews within a Nib, programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uikit

First, I am super-new to Objective-C/iOS development and, in fact, this question is for my first, test project.  Also, I come from a C#/WinForms background so I'm coming into iOS development with certain pre-conceived notions of user interface design and application state.  Please bear with me and help clear up my confusion.

I just created my first iOS application project which, consists of a Single View.  I allowed Xcode to create all the files for me through the Single View project wizard.  When it was finished, I opened my new applications, single `UIView` Nib file in the designer and I dropped three sliders onto the view.

The desired purpose of this application is very simple-- each slider corresponds to either the R, G or B values associated with the background color of my view.

I have figured out how to set the background of my view but I can not figure out how to access the values of each slider objects.  Yes, I can hook-up and respond to an `IBAction` for each slider, but my plan is that each time a slider's value changes, I want the `IBAction` to call a refactored method that accesses the values of all three sliders and then set's the views Background Color based of the values associated with each one.

How can I access the values of my sliders?  Specifically, how can I access the value of the sliders that I created by dragging and dropping them into the Nib designer window?  I've seen code explaining how to programatically add a `UISlider` to your `UIView` and then access the value, but how do you access the value of a `UISlider` that's added to the Nib and, I assume, will be automatically "wired" in at compile time?

Hopefully this makes since?  If I'm missing an intermediate step or critical concept, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create UISlider ivars/properties and make them IBOutlets:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider* yourSlider;
```

You synthesize it in your .m file and the connect the IBOutlet in interface builder. The yourSlider pointer is then a reference to the object you connected it to. Note that it will only be loaded with the view of the UIViewController and therefore will be nil until viewDidLoad is called. You also must set it back to nil

```
self.yourSlider = nil;
```

in your viewDidUnload method (so that it is released). In Xcode 4 you have a convenient way of doing all the above steps in one action (see the "Interface Builder is Built-in" of [What's new in XCode 4](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html))

Answer (score 1):

Similar to CTRL+dragging from the UISlider to the .m file to create the IBAction, you can CTRL+drag the UISlider from your .nib designer to the associated .h file and have it create a property for you. Then, from your .m file, you can access self.mySlider (or whatever you name the property).

There's a video on [this page](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/creating-outlets-and-actions-via-drag-and-drop-in-xcode-4/) that shows binding to a UISlider specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the tag property of a view.

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag

- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag
```

You can set the tag property of a view in the interface builder and later reference that view in your controller.

```
UIView *myViewFromTag = [self.view viewWithTag:theNumberYouSetInIB];
```

In general, it's better to stick with IBOutlets. However, there are certain situations where it makes more sense to use tags.

Good luck!